# Flash dynamic TLF text mixes fonts together- very weird

Tags: flash, text, flash-cs5, tlf

I'm using Flash CS5's new Text Layout Framework (TLF) for the first time.  Whenever I set the TLF text dynamically through actionscript, the resulting text renders with multiple fonts!   (The same text set statically doesn't have any issues)

Example:

[image]

I can understand if, when a client machine lacks a given font, Flash would choose a default, but in this case the font is Arial Bold, which the client does have, and moreover only certain characters are screwy.  Any ideas here??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you use dynamically changing text with Flash/TLF, you need to go into the text's properties > character panel and click the 'Embed...' button.  This will allow you to choose which range of characters of that given font to embed, ensuring that they will render correctly on every client.  You only need to do this once per font, but do it for every font you will use dynamically.

If you neglect this, Flash will selectively embed ONLY the characters of the font in the text you start out with, which is why my dynamic labels had mixed up font characters!